# jQuery .$.ajax is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook

I am using `$.ajax` for Facebook Invite and calling the URL (Yii framework controller). The `$.ajax` part of the below code is not working:

```
function FacebookInviteFriends()
{
    FB.ui
    ( 
    { 
        method : 'apprequests',
        data: '',
        display: 'dialog',
        title  : 'Invite a Friend',
        message: 'I just sent you an invitation to play My Game.',
        filters: ['app_non_users']
    }, function(response)
    {   
        alert("start"); 
        if (response && response.to) 
        {       
            alert("inside if"); 
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:83/invitechips/createRecord',
                type: 'POST',                                        
                data: {id : response.to}                    
            }).done(function() {
                alert( "Data Saved: ");
            });                               
        }
        else 
        {
            alert("inside else");                 
        }
    }
    );           
}
```

Comment: Implement the error handler to see if it's throwing an error.

Comment: Oi, [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: Maybe are you trying to Cross site script? is this script running on a resource in the same domain of localhost?

Comment: If you didn't set CORS headers in the application on the port 83, this can't work.

Comment: What is not working? No request is fired or what's the problem?

Comment: have you tried to add: `dataType:"json",`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control

Comment: If you want a detailed solution, we need to know what's the server on port 83.

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax call where you have things like url and type, you need to add something to handle errors, like :

```
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              // perform operations on error
              alert(xhr.responseText);
        },
```

so you would have

```
 $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:83/invitechips/createRecord',
                type: 'POST',   
                 error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        // perform operations on error
                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                 },                                 
                 data: {id : response.to}                    
            }).done(function() {
                alert( "Data Saved: ");
            });
```

so that you can get more details. Do you have this code hosted somewhere?

Comment: No not yet hosted. we are checking in the localhost.

Comment: ok, well add the error handling and report back, it should clear it up a bit.